# Get ID of multiple inserts in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm in the process of learning CI for myself and this came up. If I run multiple INSERTs, whether as transaction or not, is it possible to get the insert ID of each (in the proper order) instead of running `$this->db->insert_id()` one at a time for each INSERT?

For example

```
-- Get ID of each
INSERT INTO table VALUES (insert1), (insert2), (insert3)

-- What if they're called separately
INSERT INTO table VALUES (insert1)
INSERT INTO table VALUES (insert2)
INSERT INTO table VALUES (insert3)
```

Is it still possible to get the ID as an array from all this?

Comment: without rewriting some CI core files it seems you have to do it manually. but anyway, why are you trying to run away of writing such one line each time. if you like you can make a hook on insert but those suggestions seem to be overwork for simple thing

Answer (score 0):

I think you really must insert it between each inserts as far as i know, just store it in an array.

```
var $insert_id = array();

public function insert()
{
INSERT INTO table VALUES (insert1)
$this->insert_id =$this->db->insert_id();

INSERT INTO table VALUES (insert2)
$this->insert_id =$this->db->insert_id();

INSERT INTO table VALUES (insert3)
$this->insert_id =$this->db->insert_id();
}
```

everytime a database record is inserted you can still use insert_id(); after each insert then store it to an array. then you coudl make a function to return it.

```
public function get_inserted_keys()
{
  return $insert_id;
}
```

Comment: You put the values you want to insert into an array, and then insert them in a foreach, saves repeating the same code three times.

Comment: @Jeemusu, OP asked What if they're called separately

Answer (score 0):

It is simple

Controller

```
$ids    =   array();

$data[0]    =   array(blah,blah);
$data[1]    =   array(blah,blah);
$data[2]    =   array(blah,blah);

for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{
    $ids[]  =   $this->my_model->insert($data[$i]);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ids);
```

Model

```
public function insert($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('table_name',$data);
    return $this->db->insert_id()
}
```